# Navigation bar scaling issue

Tags: html, css

I have a problem where my navigation bar seems to scale with the .container in CSS. Now, I'm quite a novice but I've tried messing with the values in CSS, but to no avail. Here's the code for both the HTML and CSS:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  font-family: verdana;
  background-image: url(images/bg2.jpg);
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: auto;
  background-position: 0px 100px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-color: black;
  background-size: 100%;
}
#header {
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
#logoArea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(images/logo.png);
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
#navArea {
  height: 50%;
  float: right;
}
#nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 5%;
}
#nav a {
  color: #C8C8C8;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 75px;
  height: 50px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav li {
  width: 75px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
  background-color: #252525;
  border: 2px solid silver;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#nav li:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
.page {
  background-color: rgba(19, 19, 19, 0.9);
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}
p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.box1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(images/logo.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  float: left;
}
 
#imageLogo {
  width: 960px;
  height: 324px;
  background-image: url(images/Triicell-logo.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body a link="#C8C8C8" vlink="#C8C8C8" alink="#C8C8C8">
  <div id="Header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box1">
        <a id="logoArea"></a>
      </div>
      <div id="navArea">
        <ul id="nav">
          <li>wp_1
          </li>
          <li>wp_2
          </li>
          <li>wp_3
          </li>
          <li>wp_4
          </li>
          <li>wp_5
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="mainArea">
    <div class="container page">
      <div id="welcome">Test site</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

As I said, I'm a novice, so if there's something painfully obvious that I've missed, I'd be appreciative if you could point me in the right direction. I've been racking my brains all morning, trying to think what it could be.

Here are a couple of screenshots to reference what I'm talking about:

Before scaling the .container:
[image]

After scaling the .container:
[image]

What I'm doing to scale it is I'm changing the width of the .container to 50%;. Don't worry about anything else - I know what I'm going to do about scaling the rest, i.e. images, etc. - but it's just that navigation bar that seems to jump out of place.

But yeah, I'd be very greatful if anyone can help me with this issue. Failing that, at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please, could you explain in more details what you are trying to achieve? Also, it would help people answer if you removed parts of the CSS/HTML that are not directly relevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: @Derek and by scaling what do mean?

Comment: Certainly. I want the navigation bar to retain its position on top of the container (the dark gray area). And I'll revise over the code. And by scaling, I mean the elements change size depending on the resolution it's being viewed on. But I don't think the nav bar needs any scaling, it's just a position problem.

Comment: is this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/3qjxg2e0) what you're seeking ?

Comment: @DerekSimmons "sorry, apparently I need 10 reputation to post multiple links."  with your 10+ reputation you can post a link right?

Comment: I've added images to show what I mean. Check my main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey thanks for making your question a lot more understandable, the the thing is that if you make the container 50%, then there isn't any more room left for the nav because the #logoArea width is to big so it pushes the nav to the next line, if you want it to work you should decrease the width of the #logoArea and/or the #navArea. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yep. Your answer is on the money. My reply to my own question now states this. Thanks very much. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear floats

For this you can add the `.clear` class after `#Header`.

```
.clear{
     clear:both;
}
```

Or add `.clearfix` class in `Header`

```
#clearfix:after {
   clear: both;
   content: "";
   display: block;
}
```

Then you can manage easily you `.container` width `50%` or whatever.

and here is some mistake in your html code like-

```
 <li>wp_1</a>
          </li>
```

It should be like this -

```
 <li>
    <a href="">wp_1</a>
 </li>
```

I hope it will helps to achieve which you want.

Answer (score 0):

Ah... I see what's wrong here. There wasn't enough real estate for the navigation bar for it to be positioned where I wanted it. You see, there is supposed to be a logo beside the navigation bar, but since removing it, the navigation bar is now where I want it to be, even after scaling.

The only thing now would be to find out how to scale the navigation bar itself (i.e. make it so the nav bar changes size in correspondence to what resolution it's being displayed on), but I think that's a fight for another day.

Thank you to everyone who contributed to the question. I knew my foolishness would somehow get the better of me. Thank you, nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Since #navArea is nested inside `#Header` you would have to remove `#navArea` from the natural flow of the page to achieve what you're after.

This would look something like;

```
#navArea {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
```